# HtmlUnit property undefined script error

Tags: java, javascript, html

I’m submitting a form using java HtmlUnit package.  I am able to get pages and submit forms but on one page I’m getting a ScriptException error.  The message is “Cannot set property "disabled" of undefined to "0"”

I think it might be caused by a javascript method that tries to set a variable that has not been declared in the form but I’m not sure.

```
tempForm = MyPage.getFormByName("menu_form");
tempForm.getInputByName("userId").setValueAttribute("myusername");
HtmlPage editSubscriberPage = (HtmlPage)
tempForm.getInputByName("submit_button").click();



EcmaError: lineNumber=[824] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[script in https://labserver.comp.com/mcwebadm/cgi-bin/edit_local.pl?operation=edit&return_address=%2Fmcwebadm%2Fcgi-bin%2Fmenu.pl&selected=2322020c341b11de96c3000423d43f1d from (9, 32) to (840, 15)] message=[TypeError: Cannot set property "disabled" of undefined to "0" (script in https://myserver.company.com/mcwebadm/cgi-bin/edit_local.pl?operation=edit&return_address=%2Fmcwebadm%2Fcgi-bin%2Fmenu.pl&selected=22020c341b11de96c3000423d43f1d from (9, 32) to (840, 15)#824)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property "disabled" of undefined to "0" (script in https://labserver.comp.com/mcwebadm/cgi-bin/edit_local.pl?operation=edit&return_address=%2Fmcwebadm%2Fcgi-bin%2Fmenu.pl&selected=22020c341b11de96c3000423d43f1d from (9, 32) to (840, 15)#824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:534)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:515)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:464)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:992)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:164)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:177)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:584)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$2.run(HtmlElement.java:936)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:515)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:941)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1237)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:183)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:449)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:329)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:354)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.submit(HtmlForm.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput.doClickAction(HtmlSubmitInput.java:82)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1329)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1288)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1257)
    at TestOne.run(TestOne.java:77)
    at TestOne.main(TestOne.java:215)
```

Comment: Does viewing the same page in a browser produce a JS error?

Comment: I just tested it again and just noticed the page that loads does have a JS error.  Is there a way I can tell HtmlUnit to keep processing like ie does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused my a javascript error on the page that was being loaded.
I set the

> webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

but it still threw the exception.

SOLUTION: If you catch the ScriptException the page is STILL fully loaded and you can just continue processing and ignoring the exception.

Example of HTML that fails:

```
<html>
<Head><title>JS Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function run_js()
        {
                form.myinput.value = "from on body";
//              document.myform.myinput.value = "from body";
        }
        </script>   
    </head>

<body onload="run_js()">
    The Body.
    <form name="myform">
        <input name="myinput" type="text"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a public website to test against? As I am not able to load the JS in https://mmlab1msslnx.fmr.com/mcwebadm/cgi-bin/edit_local.pl?operation=edit&return_address=%2Fmcwebadm%2Fcgi-bin%2Fmenu.pl&selected=22020c341b11de96c3000423d43f1d

Also, please use latest HtmlUnit 2.5 version.

Comment: I'm not able to provide a public test case.  I'm working on creating one.
I have checked and I'm using version 2.5.
I was hoping someone had seen something similar to this.